# How to import GAE java project (with maven) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I'm reading this: https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-forms
and i'd like to import this project in Eclipse from 0, but i'm getting a lot of errors. (Generally any GAE projects).
What are the steps to do this?
Create new Java project, run Maven (?) and so on...
I need to use Mars 2 and have installed jdk 1.7 and 1.8.
THX.

(PS: It works using the guide. So i can run the app on cmd)

Update: errors after András Kerekes'solutions
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these steps:

1. git clone the whole [Getting Started Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java) repository
2. run mvn eclipse:eclipse in the top level directory of the cloned repository
3. import the projects into Eclipse (including the one at the top level: the project is called `getting-started-java`, you should see it in the Project Explorer) using `File > Import... > Maven > Existing Maven Projects`
4. You may see an error dialog about Maven errors, in the `Action` field, click on the cell and select to option to install the m2e connector for the JDT compiler. This will install a plugin into your Eclipse to bridge M2Eclipse and the JDT, you'll need to restart Eclipse once it finishes.
5. You may still see Maven errors like `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)`, which is OK. You dependencies should be set for the project and there should be no compilation error.
6. Ensure that the project uses JDK8 as it depends on classes that are only available since Java 8 (like `java.util.function.Function`)
7. You may want to install the [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart) plugin for additional GAE support.

Comment: perfect! thank you but now i have some problems. I'm going to post a screenshot in my answer.

Comment: The missing parent pom is because according to the screenshot you have not imported the top level project (whose pom file is `getting-started-java/pom.xml`). The missing Function class is because the project needs JDK8. (I've updated steps 3. and 6. above)

Comment: Two problems. step 3: file->import->existing project->select "getting-started-java" folder but i get the structure as you can see in the screenshot (only folders of single project, not a getting-started-java folder). This causes the import problem with pom.xml, got it. step 5: "You dependencies should be set for the project and there should be no compilation error" -> i don't understand. Can you explain it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ValeMarz you need to import them as existing Maven projects, pls see the updated step 3.

Comment: Just to note that step 2, using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, shouldn't be necessary, and I didn't need to do it. @AndrásKerekes and I weren't able to figure out why he needed it.